# How do I display vector graphics (SVG) in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Is there a way (preferably a control) to display vector graphics (preferably SVG) in a Windows Forms application?**

I'm guessing that this would be easy to do with [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), but I would prefer not to have to migrate the project.

Comment: Here are two links that might help you (never used either one, myself): [http://www.jbrowse.com/svgnet/](http://www.jbrowse.com/svgnet/) [http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgdomcsharp/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgdomcsharp/)

Answer (score 7):

[GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f4d4txw(VS.71).aspx) and the Graphics class can do vector-graphics.

For SVG, you might try to load it into the [WebBrowser control](http://ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/dv_fxmclictl/html/12667861-5b5b-46bc-8fb5-675e25264c9f.htm)...

Comment: Looks like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463862/how-can-i-display-an-svg-file-in-a-64-bit-net-application has a work-around in cases where WebBrowser control isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to migrate your project to use WPF. Windows Forms projects can embed WPF controls. Check out *[SVGImage Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92434/SVGImage-Control)*.