# How can I display an SVG file in a 64-bit .NET application?

Tags: .net, winforms, svg, 64-bit

I have an SVG file that I need to display in a .NET Windows Forms application. This is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397189/how-to-display-vector-graphics-svg-in-a-winforms-application). However, the WebBrowser control doesn't work because IE's engine doesn't render my SVG correctly (specifically it ignores the preserve whitespace directive). I looked into [Chrome](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) and [Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) controls and they worked great but they are 32-bit only and other references require the project to be compiled in 64-bit mode. Surely there must be some option for displaying correctly rendered SVG in 64-bit mode?

Comment: I ended up just using `System.Drawing.Graphics` instead of writing an SVG and displaying that. Amazing that there doesn't seem to be a solution for this though. Hopefully the WebBrowser control is a little more compliant in .NET 4.5.

Comment: +1 for IE ignoring the preserve whitespace directive. Good to know, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) with WinForms and it works excellent.

Comment: I've look at that control and it simply convert SVG into the raster image. With that approach we loose all benefits of SVG format.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [SVG Rendering Engine](http://svg.codeplex.com/). It should work in 64-bit mode since it's fully managed code.

Another option is [SharpVectors](http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/).

Comment: It doesn't contain any .NET controls. Or do you mean rendering the SVG as an image and then displaying that?

Comment: Exaclty, I mean  rendering the SVG as an image and then display it

Comment: For some reason my text does not show up when rendered as a PNG using the SVG Rendering Engine (first option).

Comment: Don't think so, not using `tspan`.