# Can the picturebox be used to display vector-based images?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, components

Can the a [PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control be used to display vector-based images?

I have read a post from someone claiming that the PictureBox can be used to display vector-based images instead of bitmap images. So the box can be resized and the picture will retain its quality like a vector image should.

So I decided to try it out, although I am looking quality. Is it a problem with my vector images not being fully vector? If this is not possible, is there another way to do this without resorting to WPF?

I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397189/how-to-display-vector-graphics-svg-in-a-winforms-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  It has be a MetaFile, not a Bitmap.  Best displayed by using the Paint() event so it can rescale on the fly as the picture box changes size.  Sample code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        PictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        image = New System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(New System.IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.schoolbus))
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, PictureBox1.ClientSize))
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Resize
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private image As System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile

End Class
```

Where "schoolbus" was a sample .wmf file I added as a resource.  The file format is the usual sticking point, there are not that many paint programs still supporting it.  You can get one [from here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/images/results.aspx?qu=Academic#ai%3aMC900410867%7C).

Comment: Thanks again Hans. Im happy to hear I don't need to resort to any third party controls not in the framework. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

**This is an outdated answer from 2012, Adobe SVG view is no longer supported.**

PictureBox does not support vector-based images. If you do not want to use WPF, you might want to download an SVG view control. Here's one from [Adobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Systems): http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/

Once you installed it, the control DLL file should be located at, for example,
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\SVG Viewer 3.0\NPSVG3.dll`.

If you add the control on your form, you can load the file as stated below.

```
AxSVGCtl1.SRC = Filename
```

*[Using Adobe's SVG control from .NET](http://www.mecxpert.de/svg/SvgDotNet.html)* shows how to use the SVG control in .NET although it is C# code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will keep this in mind in case I end up needing to go this route.

Comment: The Adobe page is now showing "Adobe SVG Viewer Discontinued".

Answer (score 0):

Use this my friend

```
                                Dim TheMetaImage As System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile
                                Dim TheStreamContentResult As System.IO.Stream = Nothing
                                Dim MyHttpClient As New HttpClient
                                TheStreamContentResult = Await MyHttpClient.GetStreamAsync(TheTabPicIcon.ImageLocation).ContinueWith(Function(TT)
                                                                                                                                         Return TT.Result
                                                                                                                                     End Function
            )
                                TheMetaImage = New System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(TheStreamContentResult)
                                Using MyG As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(TheTabPicIcon.Image)
                                    MyG.DrawImage(TheMetaImage, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, TheTabPicIcon.ClientSize))
                                End Using
```

The "TheTabPicIcon" is the picture box, while the SVG file URL stored in TheTabPicIcon.ImageLocation, you can store it anywhere you want.

Best regards